# How can I split Date column values in Access into 2 columns?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a date column that stores values for begining to end date as:
070314-073114
So I need to split it to 2 columns that has the Start Date as 070314 and End Date as 073114, any suggestions?

This database is still in Microsoft Access, and eventually after cleaning it up, we will move it to SQL Server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want these as strings and not dates?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Its an old Access mdf file that I just got access to today to do some changes, so I'm not sure why they kept that column as "Text", maybe because they've been entering both start and end date together?

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN Start_Date TEXT(6)
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN End_Date TEXT(6)

update table
set Start_Date = Left(column,6),
End_Date = Right(column,6)
```

Comment: You should add some detail explaining how you could use this query... for instance, by doing an insert into another table or etc...

Comment: @MaxVernon - something like that?

Comment: Try to imagine looking for an answer to this exact problem several months from now, without any context.  Details in the answer can help future visitors understand *why*, and not just *how*.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try your solution after I do a backup and let you know.